# Confusion about setting Camera zoom rates

Tags: android, android-camera

For a Samsung device I get:

*true* from `isZoomSupported()`,  *100* from `getMaxZoom()` & *[100, 102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123, 126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144, 147, 150, 153, 156, 159, 162, 165, 168, 171, 175, 178, 181, 184, 187, 190, 193, 196, 199, 202, 205, 208, 211, 214, 217, 220, 223, 226, 229, 232, 235, 238, 241, 244, 247, 250, 253, 256, 259, 262, 265, 269, 272, 275, 278, 281, 284, 287, 290, 293, 296, 299, 302, 305, 308, 311, 314, 317, 320, 323, 326, 329, 332, 335, 338, 341, 344, 347, 350, 353, 356, 359, 363, 366, 369, 372, 375, 378, 381, 384, 387, 390, 393, 396, 399, 402]* from `getZoomRatios()`.

Now I want to set zoom camera to zoom for **3.2x** so I call `cameraParams.setZoom(320);` I get an exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed` And I don't understand why.

As per documentation they told us:

```
isZoomSupported()
```

> Returns true if zoom is supported. Applications should call this before using other zoom methods.

```
getMaxZoom()
```

> Gets the maximum zoom value allowed for snapshot. This is the maximum value that applications can set to setZoom(int).

```
getZoomRatios()
```

> Gets the zoom ratios of all zoom values. Returns
>   List< Integer > the zoom ratios in 1/100 increments. Ex: a zoom of 3.2x is returned as 320. The number of elements is getMaxZoom() + 1. The list is sorted from small to large. The first element is always 100. The last element is the zoom ratio of the maximum zoom value.